# can we use web.config to display a text of a radio button?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to use web.config file to display a text of radio button because i don't have to re-deploy all the time. When ever I need change text of radio-button I can go intio web.config and I can change. Please let me know if this is a possible way.

Comment: sure it's possible. use key value like <add key="keyname" value="somevalue"/> under <appSettings> tah in web.config and read the config from code

Comment: I recommend use the custom user-control to make your own changes on a asp.net control  once and use it anywhere in your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, not sure why you really want this approach:

**Web.config:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="MyRadioButtonText" value="hello world!"/>
</appSettings>
```

**ASPX:**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" />
```

**VB.NET Code-Behind:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    RadioButton1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MyRadioButtonText")
End Sub
```

Comment: I have a big text , How to break the sentences?. I want to use config file so that i don't have to deploy all the time when i make changes.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, this is probably a case of "just because you can, doesn't mean you should".

> ...so don't have to re-deploy all the time...

- You may need to clarify what you meant by that. You can change this in the front end if it's not "dynamic" (which doesn't seem to be the case - re: you're looking for a web.config setting) without rebuilding/recompiling.
- So you want to modify your `web.config` and **restart** your **entire application** because of a text change?

> ***Configuration Changes Cause a Restart of the Application Domain***
>
> *Changes to configuration settings in Web.config files indirectly cause the application domain to restart. This behavior occurs by design....*
>
> See: [**MSDN**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ackhksh7.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below in web.config

```
 <appSettings>
        <add key="RadioButtonText" value="somevalue"/>
 </appSettings>
```

and from you code behind file

```
 String paramName = "RadioButtonText";

 if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[paramName] != null)
 {
      RadioButton1.Text = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[paramName];

 }
```

Comment: I have a big text , How to break the sentences?.

Comment: you mean to display the RadioButtonText into multiple lines instead of a single straight line? You can specify width for the RadioButton control or a css class which should wrap your lengthy text.

Comment: I found another way of doing it, i used &lt;br/&gt; where ever i needed breaks.

Comment: But you never know if the text length gets growing up at a later stage you'll have to change the code to put &lt;br/&gt at the appropriate places. Rather if you specify the width for the control then you don't have the change code when you update RadioButtonText as shorter or longer.